# Is it possible to enable BIOS disk password and OS suspend at the same time?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, disk-encryption

I am currently on Lenovo ThinkBook 14+ ARA. I found the BIOS offers disk lock method (Master/User Key). After setting the two keys, it is needed to enter one of them to unlock my disks when POST.

Everything works well except system suspending. When the OS suspends/sleeps (S3), it will crash and won't resume, it's true for both Windows 11 and Linux Mint 21.2. I have turned off secure boot.

I think this is because the disk will lock automatically when its power was off, which is necessary for OS to suspend. But both bios and OS won't save keys to unlock the disk. As a result, OS crashes.

I wonder if there is any possible solution to fix this problem, make the hardware encrypting method compatible with OS suspend

Comment: The regular Master / User Password in the BIOS has nothing to do with disc encryption, and it shouldn't interfere with S3.

Comment: @Albin The problem seems natural to me since the passwords are almost certainly the ATA passwords (i.e. ATA security feature set), and according to the ATA/ACS spec, powering down the drive should indeed make it go to the locked state again. I kinda doubt that there's solution since it's somewhat contradictory to S3 by nature.

Comment: If your BIOS allows you to "customize" S3 so that it does not power down the drive, you may want to be aware that it can be considered a security loophole (even though it may not be practically a problem in your particular case). And I kinda doubt that it is possible at all to implement things like "unlock on wake".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a solution for you, but (in Linux) there might be something you can do to confirm what's going on.

First of all you can check whether the passwords indeed refers to ATA passwords with `hdparm -I /dev/sdX`. If the locked system drive is an NVMe drive, you may want to try [this](https://github.com/jethrogb/nvme-ata-security) instead. (Neither am I nor am I affiliated with the author; I do not guarantee that it is safe on any aspect; it was just a Google result of my random search on "nvme ata security".)

You should be able to see whether the ATA security feature set / user password is *enabled* with the corresponding mentioned program. If so, they are referring to ATA passwords.

(By design, a drive always has a master password set, and the ATA/ACS spec [(PDF)](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Eimp/asiabsdcon2015/works/d2161r5-ATAATAPI_Command_Set_-_3.pdf) defines no way to disable it. It also clearly states in the description of the disable password command that it can only be used to disable the user password. The master password therefore has nothing to do with whether the security set is enabled. If your BIOS/UEFI shows a "state" for the master password, it either refers to its own storage for the password, or perhaps an interpretation of its current "capability" (which is some kind of "security level"). Read the spec for details on how the master password actually works -- it is not as "master" as many may intuitively think.)

Then you can further confirm whether your drive is re-locked when waken from S3, by booting e.g. a Linux Live USB. The programs mentioned should allows you to check the lock state as well (which for the record, is not the same thing as the enabled state mentioned above).

(I assume you'll be asked for password to unlock the drive regardless of the boot order. If it is not the case, you can also try to unlock it first with the program before you suspend/resume and check the lock state again.)

I am not so sure if you can implement "unlock on wake" yourself though, since even while `hdparm` is quite "self-contained" that you can simply copy the executable to a tmpfs or a filesystem on a USB drive. However, since everything else like libc and the linker and so on are not accessible anymore, unless you can workaround that by some means (static build, maybe?) and get e.g. systemd to run the program upon resumption, I don't see how one can do it. (Also, you might need to change the master password with the program first since the BIOS might have set the password to some hash of your input.) And it might mean that you need to store the password "as data" on the drive.

The other way is obviously to see if you can configure the BIOS so that it does not power down the drive for S3. I have no idea if that's technically possible at all though, but obviously you can check whether there's a setting option available anyway. Just for the record, you may want to research on / think it over whether such configuration can lead to security breach (that you care).

As a side note, ATA security feature set / passwords does not necessarily mean encryption. (And there can be encryption working behind the scene even when it has no password.) Encryption refers to the fact that the data are stored on your drive in the form of ciphertext, while a drive password / lock purely means the access via the drive firmware are prohibited before you unlock it. The data can still be stored in the form of plaintext. (AFAICT, in such cases you can only tell whether there's also encryption in effect by reading and believing in the manual / whitepaper of the drive, or, examine the sectors / flash memory "directly", i.e., not involving the firmware / controller.)

EDIT: it seems that the rust program linked above has [rotten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot) (a common thing for rust code?). Luckily it is not too hard to use [nvme-cli](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli) (which is probably available from your distro's repo like hdparm) to find out relevant information. (Using it to unlock the drive is harder, if possible, though.) **DO NOTE THAT I OFFER NO GUARANTEE OR WARRANTY OF ANY SORT FOR THE COMMANDS BELOW THOUGH.**

```
$ sudo nvme security-recv /dev/nvme0 --secp=0 --spsp=0 --nssf=0 --size=16 --al=16
NVME Security Receive Command Success
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 01 02 ef 00 00 00 00 "................"
$ sudo nvme security-recv /dev/nvme1 --secp=0 --spsp=0 --nssf=0 --size=16 --al=16
NVME Security Receive Command Success
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 "................"
```

The above command can be used to find out what "security protocols" the drive support. If you see `ef` *after* byte `7` (e.g. byte `9` or `b` as the above), it means that it implements something that is similar as / equivalent to the ATA security feature set. (It seems to be much more common than I thought.)

```
$ sudo nvme security-recv /dev/nvme0 --secp=0xef --spsp=0 --nssf=0 --size=16 --al=16
NVME Security Receive Command Success
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
0000: 00 0e 00 01 00 01 ff fe 00 29 00 00 00 00 00 00 ".........)......"
$ sudo nvme security-recv /dev/nvme1 --secp=0xef --spsp=0 --nssf=0 --size=16 --al=16
NVME Security Receive Command Success
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
0000: 00 0e 00 01 00 01 ff fe 00 29 00 00 00 00 00 00 ".........)......"
```

And the above can be used to find out whether the ATA user password is set and whether the drive is in locked state. The password is set if the "bit 1" of byte `9` ([mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) it with `0x2` with python or even bash) is 1. (`0x2` is returned after masking), and the drive is locked if the "bit 2" of the same byte (mask it with `0x4`) is is 1 (`0x4` is returned after masking). (If "bit 0" is not `1`, i.e., the byte is `0`, or, unlikely, an even number, then perhaps the drive does not actually implement the feature set.)

```
$ echo $((0x29 & 0x2))
0
$ echo $((0x29 & 0x4))
0
```

As you can see, my drives implement the feature set but do not have user password set and are not locked.

Ref.: [[1]](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil/issues/206#issuecomment-366346612) [[2]](https://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-nvme/2016-June/005189.html) [[3]](https://github.com/jethrogb/nvme-ata-security/blob/c7d404cb394f6ff0e61ebc4bcfec8b9f057f3056/user/src/nvme.rs#L336-L349)

Comment: @John `I am utterly fed up with you calling my answers wrong.` That's a good start. Get to actually learn things then.

Comment: Great answer, I learnt a lot even though I didn't find the solution. lol

Comment: I tested the output using a live stick. when the driver was unlocked, Byte 9 was 0x23, the 'bit 1' was 1, the 'bit 2' was 0. Then I suspend the OS, it took time to resume (because the driver had been locked). Byte 0 became 0x27, 'bit 2' turned to 1. Just as what you have written.